# Style with font for heading being bold italic

Tags: formatting, theorems

I have the following style.  Would like to have the font for heading be bold italic.  But modification would I need?

```latex
    \newtheoremstyle{mystyle}  % name of style
    {8pt}       % measure of space above example, e.g. {3pt}
    {8pt}       % measure of space below example, e.g. {3pt}
    {\itshape}  % name of font for body of example
    {}          % measure of space to indent, e.g. {3pt}
    {\bfseries} % name of font for heading
    {.}         % punctuation between heading and body
    { }         % space after theorem heading; { } defines an interword space
    { {\thmname{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}}
       \textcolor{DarkOrange3}{\textbf{\thmnumber{#2}}}
       \thmnote{ \textit{\texttt{\textsf{({#3})}}}} }
    
    \theoremstyle{mystyle}
    \newtheorem{theorem}{\textcolor{Green4}{Theorem}}[section]
```

Comment: `{\bfseries\itshape} % name of font for heading` presumably. But what do you expect `\textit{\texttt{\textsf{(` to do???  `\textsf` completely undoes the settings from `\texttt`

Comment: Actually, I copied it from elsewhere.

Comment: Have changed things so that I have `\thmnote{\textit{({#3})}} }` in the last line of the new style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `{\bfseries\itshape}` as name of font for heading and with changes in the last line to avoid an extra space after the theorem number.

The body and the note will share the same font but it can be modified later.

[image: d]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm} 
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}


\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}  % name of style
{8pt}       % measure of space above example, e.g. {3pt}
{8pt}       % measure of space below example, e.g. {3pt}
{\itshape}  % name of font for body of example
{}          % measure of space to indent, e.g. {3pt}
{\bfseries\itshape} % name of font for heading % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
{\textcolor{DarkOrange3}{.}}% punctuation between heading and body % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
{ }         % space after theorem heading; { } defines an interword space
{\thmname{#1}\enspace\textcolor{DarkOrange3}{\thmnumber{#2}}\thmnote{#3}} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{theorem}{\textcolor{Green4}{Theorem}}[section]

\begin{document}
    
    \section{One}   
    
    \begin{theorem}{\sffamily\footnotesize (The note argument is optional.)}\label{thm-main1}
        \begin{equation}\label{detB1}
            \det\mathbf{B}=
            \sum^n_{l =0}\sum_{I_l \subseteq n}
            \prod_{i\in I_l}(b_{ii}-\lambda_i)
            \det\mathbf{B}^{(\lambda)}(I_l |I_l ),
        \end{equation}
        where $I_l =\{i_1,\dots,i_l \}$ and $\mathbf{B}^{(\lambda)}(I_l |I_l )$
        is the principal submatrix obtained from $\mathbf{B}^{(\lambda)}$
        by deleting its $i_1,\dots,i_l $ rows and columns.
    \end{theorem}
    
\end{document}
```